# brew link mysql did not complete

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

For some some reason brew does not link mysql and it complains about permission.
I `chmod` the folder to `777` but I am still having the same issues

```
  laptop$ brew install mysql
```

Error:

```
 mysql-5.5.27 already installed, it's just not linked

 laptop$ brew link mysql

 Linking /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.27... Warning: Could not link mysql.
```

Unlinking...

```
    Error:
    Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.27/lib/plugin
    /usr/local/lib is not writable. You should change its permissions.
```

Comment: can u please update info abt your environment ?

Comment: I would think that people would know it is a **mac** because I am using the brew install...

Comment: Thaks for your  info :) i'm not much aware abt mac will  try to help you

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I figured what the problem was.
It was issues with premission and I basically did this

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib/
```

Comment: Wow - I wish I found this earlier... thank you SO MUCH!

Answer (score 1):

I believe You should:

```
sudo chmod 775 /usr/local/lib/
```

and make sure You are member of the file's group.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but a comment that may help those who are pulling out hair `chown`ing and `chmod`ing like crazy and still getting "not writeable" errors at linking. For example, from `$ brew doctor -d`

```
Error: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig isn't writable.

This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed by
by Homebrew. If a formula tries to write a file to this directory, the
install will fail during the link step.
```

I suggest you check the linked file and it's dependencies and either delete them and reinstall via homebrew, or install the package without using homebrew.

Answer (score 1):

In my system this worked perfectly.

```
chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to give a general answer to the question.
It happens that neither `/usr/local/lib/` nor `/usr/local/share`/ gives error. You should look the exact directory that is not writable. It is mentioned right after "Error: Could not symlink". So execute the command for that directory.

```
chown -R $(whoami) [/bath/to/your/dir]
```